# Holomorphic function and removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, holomorphic-functions, singularity

If a function is holomorphic on $\Bbb D$\ ${0}$, does that mean 0 is a removable singularity of the function if the residue at 0 is 0?

I think this is false because I thought I did some practice problems and sometimes the residue at poles can be 0 too. But can someone please offer me a proof? Thanks.

Comment: Consider $f(z) = 1/z^2$.

Comment: That's a counterexample. Could you tell me how to prove it? I could think of some counterexamples, but don't know how to prove it.. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean prove that it is a counterexample?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise No I meant is there a way to prove it directly, instead of providing counterexamples.

Comment: The statement is false, so providing a counterexample is a proof.

Comment: Okay. Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of singularities are possible:

$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $0$

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{123456}}$ has a pole at $0$

$f(z)=e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $0$

Comment: you meant $ e^{1/z^2}$ or $e^{1/z} - 1/z$ such that $Res(f(z),0) = 0$

Comment: yes, this is a better example